# position().left keeps returning relative to previous child but not parent

Tags: jquery, css-position

I have the following list of items. they are displayed as inline-block with `overflow-x:scroll` to the parent.

I'm trying to get the `position.left` relative to the parent but always returns `-10` the `margin-right:10` of each li element. So Hows can get the element's position.left relative to the parent?

```js
console.log(jQuery('li[data-menuanchor="about-us"]').position().left); //returns -10

console.log(jQuery('li[data-menuanchor="our-services"]').position().left); //returns -10

console.log(jQuery('li[data-menuanchor="our-products"]').position().left); //returns -10
```

```css
ul.premium-vscroll-dots-list-custom {
  background-color: #fff!important;
  opacity: .75!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
  white-space: nowrap!important;
  height: 72px!important;
  padding-top: 0!important;
  overflow-y: hidden!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  overflow-x: scroll!important;
  width: 200px!important;
}

li.premium-vscroll-dot-item {
  display: inline-block!important;
  min-width: 40px!important;
  width: auto!important;
  vertical-align: baseline!important;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
  height: 54px!important;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="premium-vscroll-dots-list-custom">
  <li data-index="0" data-menuanchor="home-banner" class="premium-vscroll-dot-item">Top</li>
  <li data-index="1" data-menuanchor="about-us" class="premium-vscroll-dot-item">About us</li>
  <li data-index="2" data-menuanchor="our-services" class="premium-vscroll-dot-item">Our Services</li>
  <li data-index="3" data-menuanchor="our-products" class="premium-vscroll-dot-item">Our Products</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I placed your code in to an executable snippet where it works absolutely fine. This would suggest that the error is either caused by some other JS or CSS, which you've not included in the question, that is acting on the page,

Comment: Also, as an aside, you *really* should avoid using `!important`. Use selector precedence to override rules properly.

Comment: thank you Rory McCrossan for the reply, do you mean you are getting values other than `-10` ?

Comment: Yes. Click the 'Run code snippet' button above.

Comment: oh yes! that is so weird..let me check and get back in a bit

Comment: tpying this in the `console.log(jQuery('li[data-menuanchor="about-us"]').position().left);` and it returned `0` .

then i tried to output from the code console.log `$('ul.premium-vscroll-dots-list-custom li.custom-active').position().left;` it actually works fine and gives non `-10` values. but i noticed one thing. when i move the horizontal scroll to the left or right slightly while keping the same `li` item `custom-active` the `$('ul.premium-vscroll-dots-list-custom li.custom-active').position().left;` the position left is unique. shouldn't it provide the same value relative to parent?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please see the above